# From integers to a data.frame (without losing the structure) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, integer

I'm trying to write a function in which:

1. I get the rows and columns numbers where I have x=="pos" using the following code

   ```
   col.numbers <- which(change.matrix2 =="pos", arr.ind=TRUE)
   ```

   I'm using this code within a function so the change.matrix2 has the exact same structure and it's always a data frame.
2. I noticed that I get col.numbers with different structures and I don't know why.

Here is what I get:

Example 1:

```
 > col.numbersA
row col 
  1   8 

> str(col.numbersA)
 Named int [1:2] 1 8
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "row" "col"

> is.integer(col.numbersA)
[1] TRUE
```

and I want to convert it to a data frame with the same structure so I use

```
> as.data.frame(t(col.numbersA))
  row col
1   1   8
```

and it works!

Example 2:

```
> col.numbersB
   row col
10   1  10
4    2  15
11   3  10
3    4  15
5    5  40
5    5  41
12   6  10
1    7   3
6    8  40
7    9  43
9   10  44
2   11   3
8   12  43

> str(col.numbersB)
 int [1:13, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:13] "10" "4" "11" "3" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "row" "col"

> is.integer(col.numbersB)
[1] TRUE
```

but when I use the same code as in Example 1 to convert it to a data frame, I get this:

```
> as.data.frame(t(col.numbersB))
    10  4 11  3  5  5 12 1  6  7  9  2  8
row  1  2  3  4  5  5  6 7  8  9 10 11 12
col 10 15 10 15 40 41 10 3 40 43 44  3 43
```

but I would like to keep the structure of col.numersB, i.e. the transpose of this.

Does anyone know how to code from integer to data.frame without losing the structure (or dimensions) of col.numbers?

Comment: Please give us data (with `dput(col.numbersA)` and `dput(col.numbersB)`. You could definitely use an `if` condition with the `length` of the object: `if(length(col.numbersX) == 2){as.data.frame(t(col.numbersX))}else{as.data.frame(col.numbersX)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col.numbersA` appears to be a named vector, while `col.numbersB` is a matrix.

You can check for dimensions before deciding whether to transpose or not. As a simple function, you can try something like:

```
myfun <- function(input) {
  if (is.null(dim(input))) as.data.frame(t(input)) else as.data.frame(input)
}
```

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(c(12, sample(5, 24, TRUE)), ncol = 5)
M
A <- setNames(c(1L, 2L), c("row", "col"))
B <- which(M == 4, arr.ind = TRUE)

myfun(A)
myfun(B)
```

You may want to try to figure out how you're ending up with a named vector rather than a one-row matrix for a single match though. The following gives me a one-row matrix, not a named vector, like you show. And `arr.ind` should always do that....

```
which(M == 12, arr.ind = TRUE)
```